# Send email with invoice in Quickbook with .net SDK

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I'm using SDK V3 for .net `IppDotNetSdkForQuickBooksApiV3` and trying to **send the email with the invoice** after I create it (which I found weird that the Quickbook doesn't do it automatically after I create the invoice, so maybe I'm doing something wrong).

So this is how it goes:

```
//Get customer
var customerQueryService = new QueryService<Customer>(context);            
var customer = customerQueryService.ExecuteIdsQuery("query to get customer");
/*I fill the invoice with data  
..      
..
..*/
//Call to generate invoice
var invoiceAdded = dataService.Add(invoice);
//Email to send
invoiceAdded.BillEmail = customer.PrimaryEmailAddr;
invoiceAdded.EmailStatus = EmailStatusEnum.NeedToSend;
invoiceAdded.EInvoiceStatusSpecified = true;
//Send Email
dataService.SendEmail(invoiceAdded);
```

This is where I'm getting troubles, first I notices that the object from `customer.PrimaryEmailAddr`has no `id`:

[image]

So when I'm gonna make the call to send the email after I created the invoice I get the following exception:

```
Object not found: EmailAddress
```

[image]

If I go to my Quickbook site I do have my customer of course and that is his email.

So what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Also quick books doesn't send the email by default because those are two separate operations in QBO, so creating an invoice in QBO does not mean that an email will be sent, unless you tell it to send an email as the invoice is created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
//Call to generate invoice

var invoiceAdded = dataService.Add(invoice);

//Send Email

dataService.SendEmail<Invoice>(invoiceAddded, customer.PrimaryEmailAddr.Address);
```

Answer (score 1):

The second argument that you pass to that method is a specific email that will override the default email in the invoice object, which should fix this bug. Basically there are two versions of the request that can be used to send invoices, there's the following:

```
POST /v3/company/<companyID>/invoice/<invoiceId>/send
```

And then this one:

```
POST /v3/company/<companyID>/invoice/<invoiceId>/send?sendTo=<emailAddr>
```

So when you pass just the invoice, it maps to the first request by taking your invoice object and figuring out what the id is, a lot of those fields however don't get filled by default by QBO for some reason, this would be why you are getting an error with passing just the invoice, because for some reason it relies on that email having an id which I guess QBO doesn't auto-fill for you, so what I would do is use the other overload for this method which maps to the second request, which explicitly sets the email address in the request, that way no matter what, as long as you passed a valid email address, and the invoice exists, the request can't fail, otherwise you're relying on a bunch of data getting filled properly which leaves you open to a lot of bugs, the QuickBooks API in general is very, very prone to bugs and doesn't really help you out when you get them, so in general the less bugs you expose yourself to, the better in my opinion.